# How do I access the next token of the url in django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, templates

In one of my template, I'm trying to access the next token or the name of the view I'm supposed to go to if I were logged. Is it possible to access this information within the template ?

**Edit 1 :**

What I would write in the url even though I'm not logged in :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

And this would redirect me there url wise :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=home

Comment: Does the page sequence differ?  i.e. if you're on page X, will page Y always be next, or could it be page Z?

Comment: It depends. Let's say you want to go to the homepage then you'll be redirected to the homepage. However, if you wrote profile you'll go on the profile page.

Comment: How does the user choose the next page?  Do they click a link, or type into an input box, or some other way?